# Chip setoncheckedchangelistener String comparison return false

Tags: android, kotlin, android-chips

[image]

**Some Context :** I'm filtering trip according to their date, those trips are on firebase, I have a method(**getTripState**) that compare the current date to the trip date and either return "Upcoming" or "Old Trips" depending on the case. The chips play the role as switch button with single selection enabled. I filter tripArray based on the chip text is equal to the date in the trip. Even if the String are exactly the same, the comparison return false.

```
chipGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { chipGroup, i ->
        val chip: Chip = chipGroup.findViewById(i)

        rvHome.adapter = TripHistoryAdaptor(context, tripsArray.filter {
            Toast.makeText(context, (it.date.getTripState() == chip.text).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Toast.makeText(context, "${it.date.getTripState()} == ${chip.text} ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            it.startAt.getTripState() === chip.text

        } as ArrayList<Trip>)

        (rvHome.adapter as TripHistoryAdaptor).notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Comment: try to debug and check the values of it.date.getTripState() and chip.text

Comment: I did that, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of `case-sensitive comparison`. see my below example

```
val first = "kotlin"
val second = "kotlin"
val firstCapitalized = "KOTLIN"

println(first == second) // output: True
print(first == firstCapitalized) // output: False [becuase uppercase and lowercase]
```

So you can compare string by converting your string to `lowercase` like below.

```
val first = "kotlin"
val second = "kotlin"
val firstCapitalized = "KOTLIN"

println(first == second) // output: True
print(first.toLowerCase() == firstCapitalized.toLowerCase()) // output: True
```

Another way, you can use the `equals method` and `pass true` for the `second optional parameter` ignoreCase:

```
val first = "kotlin"
val second = "kotlin"
val firstCapitalized = "KOTLIN"

println(first.equals(second)) // output: True
print(first.equals(firstCapitalized, true)) // output: True
```

Comment: The string are exactly the same. But still failed. thanks